# Need of creating dedicated Android and IPhone Applications

Tags: android, iphone, web-applications

I want to know that what is the reason of creating dedicated e-commerce(web application) applications for every mobile OS ?

As I have seen that for ebay.com,they have a desktop version of website,they have mobile version of website ,they have android application as well as IPhone application.Same is the case with Social networking websites like Facebook,Twitter ,linked in and also for job portal like monsterindia.

Now my question :

What is the need of creating dedicated applications from scratch for every mobile OS with having a mobile version of website available.I came up with a reason that may be for performance it is preferred to develop dedicated applications.

Please let me know what is base reason for developing these dedicated applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A native application developed for the **iPhone** and **Android**
   will need to run on its proprietary **iOS** and **Android**
   platform, or on Symbian for many Nokia devices, and so forth. A Web
   app, however, is typically coded in a browser-rendered language such
   as HTML combined with JavaScript.
2. One interesting point to note is that while architectural
   differences will likely remain between a native and Web application
   for some time, the user experiences provided by both interfaces are
   increasingly blurred, as most native apps utilize real-time Web
   connectivity and Web apps provide offline modes that can be accessed
   without network connectivity. As a result, some of these apps are
   now referred to as hybrid apps.
3. Native apps definitely enjoy an architectural advantage in security, as they do not need to connect with the network as frequently as Web apps and, in some cases, skip the process altogether.

Comment: from your answer i am getting that for security issues only we create native , but what is the risk if we are doing transactions using mobile version of the website ?

Answer (score 1):

Web views render things differently and perform differently on different devices and on different OSs.

I haven't done any iOS work, but I have seen performance problems in particular when using scrolling lists inside Android web views, and it can be tricky to get video working correctly. Try searching for WebView-related Android posts and you'll start to see how many problems people have.

It does cost more to develop a separate app for each mobile OS, but I think it is still the only way to end up with a really polished result in all but the most simple cases.

Comment: thanks for replying but what is the main reason for creating apps ?? for performance it is ok but what are the other reasons ??